# Functions homework

Tags: python, function

My apologies as I am very new to Python and coding in general but I am trying an exercise on creating functions and formatting all in the same. Here I have a function I wrote for practice. But I can't get it to run correctly. What am doing wrong with creating this function.

My code:

```
def greeting(name):
  name = input("What's your name: ")
  return "Hi %s" % name

print(greeting())
```

The error:

```
TypeError: greeting() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You have defined your function to require an argument, but then in your function, you overwrite that variable with user input.

Comment: I recommed revisiting your lessons and tutorials on how to define Python functions. Specifically, what the meaning or purpose of code inside the `(...)` of a function definition. Here's the one from the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Thank you @GinoMempin I will definitely review that documentation. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to give name as a parameter to the greeting function.
Try this:

```
def greeting():
  name = input("What's your name: ")
  return "Hi %s" % name

print(greeting())
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to take `name` as an argument, because you are creating that variable within the function in your call to `input()`

```
def greeting():
  name = input("What's your name: ")
  return "Hi %s" % name
```

You also do not need to `print()` the function, because it's return value (a string) is printed by default. If you saved the return value of `greeting()` into an object, you could then print that object

```
the_greeting = greeting()
print(the_greeting)
```